# Cannot navigate to page which was called once before

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

Short intro into my application's-logic:
My application is using a REST-Api and needs a token for all requests but a specific one (let's call it "pairing-page").
Before I navigate to any of my pages I'm checking the target location. If my target is the page where I'm requesting the token, no checking for a existing token is made. 
For every other page a token is necessary. If no token exists the user should navigate back to the "pairing-page".
My start-Page is my paring-page.

What's the problem?:
When starting the app (pairing-page) and getting the token and navigating to the 2nd page - let's call it "overview" - everything is ok. The overview has a button which calls a method that removes my token and navigates back to the pairing-page. That's working as well.

Now the interesting part:
When I try to pair & navigate to the overview again (2nd time), no navigation is done. By this I mean my overview is not popping up.

I'm using Xamarin's Shell Navigation and overriding the OnNavigating-Method.

Code:

```
protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    // check if BearerToken exist. If so, navigate to Overview
    if (args.Target.Location.ToString() != "//Admission.Event.Pair"
        && args.Target.Location.ToString() != "Admission.Event.Pair")
    {

        App app = App.Current as App;
        string bearerToken = RestServiceCalls.GetBearerToken(app._dependencyService);

        // if a the token is missing call the Pairing-Page
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(bearerToken) 
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bearerToken))
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => { await NavigateToPageAsync("Admission.Event.Pair"); });
            return;
        }
    }

    base.OnNavigating(args);
}

async Task NavigateToPageAsync(object pageName, bool animate = true)
{
    await Xamarin.Forms.Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{pageName.ToString()}", animate);
    Xamarin.Forms.Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;
}
```

Let's take a look into the args:

Application start, pairing-page:
**args.Target.Location: //Admission.Event.Pair

args.Current.Location: null**
The Pairing-Page is popping up, everything is ok.

Click on the Button which processes getting a token and after that navigating to the overview:
**args.Target.Location: Admission.Event

args.Current.Location: //Admission.Event.Pair**
The overview page is popping up, everything is ok. Got a valid token as well.

Click on Button which processes removing the token and navigating to the pairing-page:
**args.Target.Location: Admission.Event.Pair

args.Current.Location: //Admission.Event.Pair/Admission.Event**
The token is removed correctly (is null) and the pairing-page pops up. Everything is ok.

Now the problem occurs:
When I'm now trying to get a token and navigate to the overview again my args have this content and my overview wont show up:
**args.Target.Location: Admission.Event

args.Current.Location: //Admission.Event.Pair/Admission.Event/Admission.Event.Pair**

Any idea about that?
My first thought was it might be an issue with the target-location.

Comment: have you used the debugger to verify that is actually executing the Navigation in the problem case?

Comment: You mean if OnNavigating is executed and calling the base.OnNavigating(args)? If so: Yes, I have :/.

Comment: no, is it actually reaching `NavigateToPageAsync("Admission.Event.Pair")`?

Comment: Yes. Everything is okay.
BUT! It seems like the shell doesn't support multiple calls of pages in the navigation stack. 
For me I could simple use 

if (shell != null){  
 INavigation navigation = shell.Navigation;  
 navigation.PopToRootAsync();  
}

Edit: I hate formatting in Commets -_-

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment:

For me I could simple use:

```
if(shell != null){ 
  INavigation navigation = shell.Navigation; 
  navigation.PopToRootAsync(); 
}
```